# How to get data through eloquent relation

Tags: php, laravel

I got this form in which you select a client and it inserts the client_id into the db

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="clientId">Client</label>
    <select name="client_id" class="form-control">
        @foreach($clients as $client)
            <option value="{{$client->client_id}}">
                {{$client->client_name}}
            </option>
        @endforeach 
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
```

My project controller is this

```php
public function index()
{
    return view('projects.index', [
        'projects' => Project::all(),
        'client' => Client::all(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    if (Auth::user()->role != 'admin') {
        return redirect()->back();
    } else {
        return view('projects.create',[
            'project' => new Project,
            'clients' => Client::all(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

So I want to display the client name from the client_id for every project, this is my index

```php
<tbody class=""> 
    @foreach ($projects as $project)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $project->proj_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $project->proj_title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $project->proj_desc }}</td>
            <td>{{ $project->client->client_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $project->created_by }}</td>
            <td>{{ $project->created_at }}</td>
            @if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin')
            <td>
```

Client model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'client_id';

    protected $fillable = ['client_name','client_id'];

    public function projects () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
    }
}
```

Project model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'proj_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'proj_title',
        'proj_desc',
        'client_id',
        'created_by'
    ];

    public function clients (){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Client');
    }
}
```

So, how can I retrieve the data from my index? I tried like it is in the documentation but I always get an error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your relationship is called `clients` but your are trying to access `$project->client` in your view.

Comment: Could you post what error you are getting.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Client can **have one/many** projects, you should define the inverse of the relation on the projects model. This would become: one project **belongs to** one client.

In code:
**Project Model**

```php
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}
```

You could also notice that inverse relation because you are storing the foreign key (**client_id**) on the **projects** table.
If you use `has one`, Laravel would look for the foreign column on the related model table (`clients` in your example).

**Note:** in your view you are calling `client->client_name`, but you defined the relation as `clients` (plural). I'd rename the relation to `client` (singular) as it better describes it

Answer (score 0):

In your projects controller:

```php
return view('projects.index', [
    'projects' => Project::with('clients')->get(),
]);
```

In your view:

```html
<td>{{$project->clients->client_name}}</td>
```

Since you named the project->client relationship on your Project model as clients despite being a hasOne relationship.

Also I would define the project->client relationship as a `BelongsTo` instead of a `HasOne`.